# Ingress responding with 'default backend - 404' when using GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Using the latest Kubernetes version in GCP (`1.6.4`), I have the following `Ingress` definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myproject
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: staging.myproject.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /poller
        backend:
          serviceName: poller
          servicePort: 8080
```

Here is my service and deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: poller
  labels:
    app: poller
    tier: backend
    role: service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: poller
    tier: backend
    role: service
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: poller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: poller
        tier: backend
        role: service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: poller
        image: gcr.io/myproject-1364/poller:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: staging
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

In my `/etc/hosts` I have a line like:

```
35.190.37.148 staging.myproject.io
```

However, I get `default backend - 404` when curling any endpoint on `staging.myproject.io`:

```
$ curl staging.myproject.io/poller/cache/status
default backend - 404
```

I have the exact same configuration working locally inside Minikube, with the only difference being the domain (`dev.myproject.io`), and that works like a charm.

I have read and tried pretty much everything that I could find, including stuff from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx#running-multiple-ingress-controllers) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/controllers/gce/BETA_LIMITATIONS.md#disabling-glbc) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/349), but maybe I'm just missing something... any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the output of:
`kubectl describe ingress`

Answer (score 14):

It does take 5-10 minutes for an Ingress to actually become usable in GKE. In the meanwhile, you can see responses with status codes 404, 502 and 500.

There is an ingress tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer I recommend following it. Based on what you pasted, I can say the following:

- You use service.Type=NodePort, which is correct.
- I am not sure about the `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation, maybe that's the issue.
- Make sure your application responds `200 OK` to `GET /` request.
- Also I realize you `curl http://<ip>/` but your Ingress spec only handles `/poller` endpoint. So it's normal you get `default backend - 404` response while querying `/`. You didn't configure any backends for `/` path in your Ingress spec.

Comment: My problem with this issue was the lack of `200 OK` at the base of the domain. I just plugged a blank 200 response, waited a couple minutes, and it worked just as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is facing this problem, check if header `Host` is correct and matches expected domain.